# Having Trouble Running PyInstaller-produced binary on Mac OSX

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyinstaller

I have a PyQT project that I have currently developed on my Mac OSX system and I am wishing to distribute the project as a binary to be used on a clean Mac OSX system.

I am producing this binary with the following command

```
pyinstaller --noconsole --windowed myscript.py
```

However, when I attempt to run the binary on my clean system, the thread crashes with the following response.

```
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   PyQt4.QtCore.so                 0x000000010a238df6 qpycore_pyqtSignal_New(char const*, bool*) + 108
1   PyQt4.QtCore.so                 0x000000010a239121 qpycore_get_lazy_attr + 189
```

I have no idea what is going on here, the produced shared object file exists, but the call to `qpycore_pyqtSignal_New(char const*, bool*) + 108` always crashes my system.

I have used pip to install and use pyinstaller.

**EDIT:** The produced binary works flawlessly on my own system.

Comment: I have the same problem, except it crashes in either: `PyRun_SimpleStringFlags` starting with `normalizeTypeInternal`